# Compile error in Moveit "Getting started" documentation

Tags: ros2, moveit, ubuntu, colcon

First, let me make an observation unrelated to my question:
After going through most of the getting started documentation (https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html), I think it'd be better to base the documentation off of pre-compiled packages, and then move to building your own binaries if it becomes necessary.  I'm pretty sure I already had most of the packages I needed installed before I started the MoveIt documentation, so the build errors I've been running into are probably unnecessary.  And most have probably been caused by using a WSL2 Ubuntu install on windows, which has a few minor differences (such as a shared PATH environment variable).

That said, I'm running through the MoveIt getting started documentation (in a Windows WSL2 instance) and can't get past the compile step:

`colcon build --mixin release`

There's the following error:

````
...
[Processing: moveit_setup_app_plugins, moveit_setup_controllers, moveit_setup_core_plugins, moveit_setup_srdf_plugins, moveit_task_constructor_visualization]
[Processing: moveit_setup_app_plugins, moveit_setup_controllers, moveit_setup_core_plugins, moveit_setup_srdf_plugins, moveit_task_constructor_visualization]
[Processing: moveit_setup_app_plugins, moveit_setup_controllers, moveit_setup_core_plugins, moveit_setup_srdf_plugins, moveit_task_constructor_visualization]
--- stderr: moveit_task_constructor_visualization
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [motion_planning_tasks/src/CMakeFiles/motion_planning_tasks_rviz_plugin.dir/build.make:203: motion_planning_tasks/src/CMakeFiles/motion_planning_tasks_rviz_plugin.dir/remote_task_model.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [motion_planning_tasks/src/CMakeFiles/motion_planning_tasks_rviz_plugin.dir/build.make:245: motion_planning_tasks/src/CMakeFiles/motion_planning_tasks_rviz_plugin.dir/task_panel.cpp.o] Error 1
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [motion_planning_tasks/src/CMakeFiles/motion_planning_tasks_rviz_plugin.dir/build.make:217: motion_planning_tasks/src/CMakeFiles/motion_planning_tasks_rviz_plugin.dir/task_display.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:450: motion_planning_tasks/src/CMakeFiles/motion_planning_tasks_rviz_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< moveit_task_constructor_visualization [3min 1s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< moveit_setup_core_plugins [9min 32s]
Aborted  <<< moveit_setup_controllers [9min 36s]
Aborted  <<< moveit_setup_srdf_plugins [9min 37s]
Aborted  <<< moveit_setup_app_plugins [9min 38s]

Summary: 54 packages finished [11min 41s]
  1 package failed: moveit_task_constructor_visualization
  4 packages aborted: moveit_setup_app_plugins moveit_setup_controllers moveit_setup_core_plugins moveit_setup_srdf_plugins
  5 packages had stderr output: moveit_configs_utils moveit_setup_controllers moveit_setup_core_plugins moveit_setup_srdf_plugins moveit_task_constructor_visualization
  5 packages not processed
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a `g++` issue than a MoveIt issue. I base my statement on the error message, which says

> c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus

You can maybe try updating your compiler to the latest version: `sudo apt install build-essential` and then try to build again.

Also, can you try out a simple build? That would involve not using the `--mixin release` part of it. AFAIK, the default build type should be release, in order to be optimised for runtime. This would eliminate any extra sources of problems.

It might also be a memory issue, as pointed out in [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107483) particular thread. You can try running `dmesg` right after the build fails to see if it complains about being out of memory or something similar.

Comment: It looks like this was a memory issue.  I'd forgot to check that after I'd spent days figuring out that the build was failing because Ubuntu was including windows PATHs (which have a different version of ROS2, etc. installed).  I added `--executor sequential` to single-thread the build and it worked (I think).